# Network communication between apps

Tags: c#, networking

Hello I will be constructing two test applications, one to run on a user computer. It will be a system tray kind of background app to manage the contents of a specified folder. The other will be an Admin kind of screen to show what computers in the current network are running the first app and read some data (contents of folders).

How can I transmit data across the network to see specific data from my apps? Again I only want to see what apps are running and what data they are sending (from the Admin screen).

Comment: honestly i was hoping for more specifics, I don't know if there is good terminology for what I'm trying to accomplish. should I rephrase the question or what?

Comment: Have you tried to do what you've described?  Do you have code that demonstrates a particular failure?  If you're just looking for a way to communicate over a network, try setting up a WCF service running as a Windows service and reading that over net.tcp from your admin screen.

Comment: Yes so I've got the skeleton forms ready. But I don't know how to send that data from one app to the other. I've been searching, I have VS 2010 express, will I not have a WCF template available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interapp communications is ideally suited to [ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) which is an asynchronous messaging library with a socket-style API and no need for a broker - there is a good [C# Binding](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aclr).

Code sample:

```
var publisher = new ZmqPublishSocket {
    Identity = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(),
    RecoverySeconds = 10
};

publisher.Bind( address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:9292" );

// Add a subscriber.
var subscriber = new ZmqSubscribeSocket();

subscriber.Connect( address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:9292" );
subscriber.Subscribe( prefix: "" ); // subscribe to all messages

// Add a handler to the subscriber's OnReceive event
subscriber.OnReceive += () => {
    String message;
    subscriber.Receive( out message, nonblocking: true );

    Console.WriteLine( message );
};

// Publish a message to all subscribers.

publisher.Send( "Hello world!" );
```